# How to wait until subscription from SUB socket is registered on PUB side when using ZeroMQ?

Tags: python, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I have message bus that only forwards messages from its PULL socket to PUB socket. It works as a communication medium for other pieces of the system that use PUSH socket to send messages and SUB socket to receive them.

Most of the communication over the bus happens between daemons. But there can also be programs that connect to the bus, immediately send a question, wait for someone to reply and disconnect.

Problem is that subscribing with SUB socket is not blocking operation. Subscription might not have been registered in message bus PUB socket before someone has already replied to the question.

Here is example where 20 of `ephemeral_program`s connect to the bus, send message and expect to receive that same message back from the bus.

Some of them receive the message but some don't. One unreliable solution is to sleep for a small period of time before sending the message. Better one is doing subscription check in a loop by sending messages to the bus until one of them is received. I don't really like this because it's basically polling operation, not just a single acknowledgement from publisher when it is ready.

But is this the only way or is there some socket option or another one-to-many socket pair for subscriber/listener side to ensure the publisher side has registered the subscription?

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

from zmq import Context, Poller, Socket
from zmq.constants import POLLIN, PUB, PULL, PUSH, SUB


def message_bus():
    context = Context.instance()
    in_socket: Socket = context.socket(PULL)
    in_socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/in-socket.ipc")
    out_socket: Socket = context.socket(PUB)
    out_socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/out-socket.ipc")

    while True:
        msg = in_socket.recv_string()
        out_socket.send_string(msg)


# Daemon to create some traffic
def daemon():
    context = Context.instance()
    receive_socket: Socket = context.socket(SUB)
    receive_socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/out-socket.ipc")
    receive_socket.subscribe("")
    send_socket: Socket = context.socket(PUSH)
    send_socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/in-socket.ipc")

    poller = Poller()
    poller.register(receive_socket, POLLIN)

    while True:
        polling_result = poller.poll(timeout=1)

        if polling_result:
            receive_socket.recv_string()
        else:
            send_socket.send_string("Hi!")


def ephemeral_program(i):
    context = Context.instance()

    send_socket: Socket = context.socket(PUSH)
    send_socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/in-socket.ipc")

    receive_socket: Socket = context.socket(SUB)
    receive_socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/out-socket.ipc")
    receive_socket.subscribe(f"ephemeral_program_{i}")

    poller = Poller()
    poller.register(receive_socket, POLLIN)

    # time.sleep(1)
    # This would in most cases give enough time to register the
    # subscription on the PUB side.

    # Better option is to confirm subscription using loop
    # while True:
    #    send_socket.send_string(f"ephemeral_program_{i}:am I subscribed?")
    #    polling_result = poller.poll(timeout=1)
    #
    #    if polling_result:
    #        msg = receive_socket.recv_string()
    #        if msg == f"ephemeral_program_{i}:am I subscribed?":
    #            print("Subscription confirmed")
    #            break
    #    else:
    #        print("Not yet subscribed")

    # Could be question to someone else
    send_socket.send_string(f"ephemeral_program_{i}:Hello")
    polling_result = poller.poll(timeout=100)

    if polling_result:
        print(receive_socket.recv_string())
    else:
        print("Did not receive message")


message_bus_p = Process(target=message_bus, args=())
message_bus_p.start()

n = 20
daemons_p = [Process(target=daemon, args=()) for _ in range(n)]
for daemon_p in daemons_p:
    daemon_p.start()

# Allow the message bus and daemons to ramp up as if they've
# been running for some time
time.sleep(0.2)

ephemeral_programs_p = [
    Process(target=ephemeral_program, args=(i,)) for i in range(n)
]
for ephemeral_program_p in ephemeral_programs_p:
    ephemeral_program_p.start()
for ephemeral_program_p in ephemeral_programs_p:
    ephemeral_program_p.join()

for daemon_p in daemons_p:
    daemon_p.kill()

message_bus_p.kill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using XPUB and XPUB_VERBOSE socket option you are able to read arrived subscriptions and send acknowledgement message. Then just wait acknowledgment in `ephemeral_program`.

```py
from zmq import Context, Poller, Socket
from zmq.constants import POLLIN, PULL, PUSH, SUB, XPUB, XPUB_VERBOSE


def message_bus():
    context = Context.instance()
    in_socket: Socket = context.socket(PULL)
    in_socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/in-socket.ipc")
    out_socket: Socket = context.socket(XPUB)
    out_socket.bind("ipc:///tmp/out-socket.ipc")
    out_socket.setsockopt(XPUB_VERBOSE, True)

    poller = Poller()
    poller.register(in_socket, POLLIN)
    poller.register(out_socket, POLLIN)

    while True:
        socks = dict(poller.poll())

        if in_socket in socks:
            msg = in_socket.recv_string()
            out_socket.send_string(msg)
        if out_socket in socks:
            msg = out_socket.recv_multipart()
            first_part = msg[0]
            subscription_prefix = b'\x01'
            if first_part.startswith(subscription_prefix):
                topic_bytes = first_part[len(subscription_prefix) :]
                topic = str(topic_bytes, encoding="UTF8")
                out_socket.send_string(f"{topic}:subscription_ack")

def ephemeral_program(i):
    context = Context.instance()

    send_socket: Socket = context.socket(PUSH)
    send_socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/in-socket.ipc")

    receive_socket: Socket = context.socket(SUB)
    receive_socket.connect("ipc:///tmp/out-socket.ipc")
    poller = Poller()
    poller.register(receive_socket, POLLIN)

    receive_socket.subscribe(f"ephemeral_program_{i}")

    # Wait for subscription ack or any message with subscribed topic
    polling_result = poller.poll(timeout=10000)
    if polling_result:
        msg = receive_socket.recv_string()
        print(f"Subscription confirmed {msg}")
    else:
        print("Couldn't subscribe")
        return

    # Could be question to someone else
    send_socket.send_string(f"ephemeral_program_{i}:Hello")
    polling_result = poller.poll(timeout=100)

    if polling_result:
        print(receive_socket.recv_string())
    else:
        print("Did not receive message")
```